# How can I get wifi/audio/bluetooth/track pad working on my Dell 5770 with FIPS kernel?

Tags: 20.04, dell

Prior to enabling FIPS on my Ubuntu 20.04 install my kernel was 5.15.0-88-generic #98~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 9 16:43:45 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux and everything worked fine on the laptop.

Once I enabled FIPS my kernel became 5.4.0-1024-fips #28+recert1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 14 21:30:13 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, now bluetooth, wifi, trackpad, and sound don't work.

Canonical/Ubuntu please fix or update your kernel to work with this laptop.

Or does anyone have some fixes, please?